# ogr2ogr elasticsearch export to a shapefile

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr

http://www.gdal.org/drv_elasticsearch.html

Is it possible to export a elasticsearch index into a shapefile using something like:

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs crs:84 test.shp ES:http://localhost:9200`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the index and type (separated by an underscore) to the command, after the ES connection parameter.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs crs:84 test.shp ES:http://localhost:9200 index_type
```

This isn't stated in the documentation at http://www.gdal.org/drv_elasticsearch.html, although it does suggest you can specify the index/type with the ogrinfo command.  I ran into the same issue so I just tried it with ogr2ogr and it worked.